# What's the best way of adding/removing a specific item from List<T> in multi-threading scenario

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have now a scenario that needs to add and remove items in multi-threading condition

I'm doing

```
lock(list)
{
    if(!list.Contains(item))
    {
        list.Add(Item);
    }
}
```

and

```
lock(list)
{
    if(list.Contains(item))
    {
        list.Remove(Item);
    }
}
```

But I have now a very big problem with race condition. The lock time is increasing and incrasing.

I wished I could use ConcurrentBag but it doesn't has Contains Method, so I can't remove the specific item I want to remove.

I'm now using ConcurrentDicionary as a temporary solution. but it's definitely not the proper way to do it.

So my question is how can I solve this problem? Is there any lock free implementation for things like this out there? Because none of the Collections under Concurrent name space suit for this problem.

Comment: I think you need to explain why `ConcurrentDictionary` isn't satisfactory for your situation because we'd have a better idea what the issue is.

Comment: BTW, this is probably just a typo in the question, but your remove has a bug, you don't want the negation in the contains check.

Comment: yes that was a typo, I'll edit it. And for ConcurrentDictionary, because there's no key, just object. so if I want to use ConcurrentDicionary it'll be like ConcurrentDictionary<Item,Item>

Comment: Where is the lock contention occuring?  The add/remove are fairly quick, so that's not likely the place where you're getting blocked (unless you're doing a LOT of adds/removes.)  Are you enumerating the collection somewhere inside a lock and doing long-running operations with the elements?  If so, you can get better performance by making a copy (in a lock) and then enumerating on the copy (outside the lock).  On a side note, you can call Remove without doing the Contains check; it will just return false if there is nothing to remove.

Comment: @user696604 Sure, but my guess is that the lock time is increasing with the size of the collection because finding an item in a list is O(n) whereas finding an item in a Dictionary is O(1). List<T>.Remove is a linear search too.

Comment: Also, it's not actually a race condition, you avoid that by having the locks. It's more of an performance issue. Not sure if there's a more specific description.
Do you know if there's an exess of calls to add where the item is already on the list and to remove where the item is not on the list?

Comment: I only have lock on this 2 places, and I'm having like 4 writer and 4 reader, and the locking time is becoming unacceptable with collection size >10000. I'm iterating somewhere else but without lock, i'm using for not foreach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a concurrent version of [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). `ConcurrentBag<T>` wasn't meant for that, it's for support of efficient producer-consumer scenarios. There isn't any such collection in the Framework.

So, you could use `ConcurrentDictionary<Item, Item>`, as you said. But I agree with you that it's not an ideal solution.

Or, you could replace your locking code that uses `List<T>` with one that uses `HashSet<T>`. Operations like `Contains()` and `Remove()` can be very slow on large lists. But they should be fast in hash sets, which should improve your performance significantly, if your collection is large enough.

It's also possible there is some third-party library that contains something like `ConcurrentHashSet<T>`, but I don't know about any.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I'll stick on this for a while. btw do you know how's contains method implemented in List<T>, don't tell me it's iterating the whole list XD

Comment: @liiir1985 That's what I said in my comment to your original post. Both `Contains` and `Remove` are linear search and therefore O(n).

Comment: Just tested HashSet<T> and it indeed solved the problem, many thanks. So I think I'll just wait and see if there's a 3rd party concurrent version of that

Answer (score -1):

Just create a meaningless object for your locking control:

```
object listLock = new object();

lock(listLock)
{
    if(!list.Contains(item))
    {
        list.Add(Item);
    }
}
```

I believe this is generally the standard way to do locking because of the issue that you've described above.

Comment: While this is better than locking the list, it doesn't address the issue in the question.

Comment: what's the difference if I lock a extra lock object than locking the list itself? doesn't it has the same effect in this case? I don't quite understand

Comment: Why better? Since the object on which the operation is carried out is a simple list, I would say that having another object just adds complexity. I would recommend using another object only when there's is a chance that code elsewhere could be have unrelated operations on the object that requires locking.

Comment: If the list is exposed you would need to expose the sync object anyway, which users would be required to use. Not very good design, since other coders would need to know that. You would be better off exposing a copy list function, or methods to add/remove that locks the list.

Comment: BTW, not my downvote on the answer. Using a sync object is good in many other cases.